# if i want to check WeeklyTestTable from '2016-11-31' to '2016-11-31' it is giving me error because november had only 30 days in 2016

Tags: java, sql-server

i have one table named "WeeklyTestTable" and i have to check all the details of student during certain month like from february to march or jan to feb. the problem is that if i want to check WeeklyTestTable from '2016-11-31' to '2016-11-31' it is giving me **"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"** because november had only 30 days in 2016. just like that if i check from '2016-08-31' to '2016-09-31' it gives same error as september had only 30 days. The problem is that i can not change the date, date have to be same between the months. so is there any option in sql which can round the date so i can get my required result. i am using sql with java so if there is an option in java which can tell me that certain month has only 30,31,29 or 28 days so i can change the date before sending it to the sql servers.

Edit:
Actually my table has the information of tests given by individual student and i wanted to check the number of test he/she has passed during certain month and also it depends on when he/she got enrolled in the institution. for examples suppose a person **A** enrolled in the institution on '2016-08-31'. if i wanted to check his test on the month of september so i'll start with the previous month which is 'august' and his day of admission which is '31' so my query would be 'select * from table where rollno = something and class = something and date between '2016-08-31' and '2016-09-31' but since there is no 31st in september therefore my query is giving the above error. 
in database datatype of date is date and i'm sending string like this :

```
try {                              

ps = con.prepareStatement("select COUNT(Marks) as testPassed from WeeklyTestTable where (Date_of_Entry between '"+another_fee.sprevious_year+"-"+another_fee.sprevious_month+"-"+another_fee.sprevious_date+"' and '"+another_fee.scurrent_year+"-"+another_fee.scurrent_month+"-"+another_fee.scurrent_date+"') and Roll_No="+student_info[i][0]+" and Class='"+student_info[i][3]+"' and(Marks >= 5)");
                    rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                    test_info[i] = rs.getInt(1);               
                    }
```

where previous date = current date

please pardon my english

Comment: Where did you get the dates from in the first place? How did you end up with `2016-11-31`? Show the code.

Comment: "November had only 30 days in 2016" - There was nothing unusual about 2016 here...

Comment: Please be more specific and post the code from the starting date parameter up to the point where you send your SQL query. It's impossible to tell you the easiest or most concise way to achieve what you want if we don't know if your starting date is passed as a long, a Date, a LocalDateTime object or even a String. It's also important to know which data type is used for the particular column in the database which stores the dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Java 8 solution

[`YearMonth::atEndOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#atEndOfMonth--) returns [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

[`YearMonth::lengthOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#lengthOfMonth--) returns an `int` integer number of days in the month.

---

#### Pre Java 8 solution

```
public static int lengthOfMonth(int year, int month) {
    GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1, 1);
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    return c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
```

Comment: can you please guide me how to add LocalDate package in my java. Actually i'm new to java therefore i'm having difficulty to use javadoc and oracle website

Comment: also i'm using jdk 7 and i think localdate is not available in jdk 7 so is there any alternating option.

Comment: Added JDK 7 compatible solution. It basically works by going to the first day of the next month and then going back by one day.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a starting date, and want the corresponding dates for upcoming months, i.e. dates with the same day-of-month, then just use the [`plusMonths(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths-long-) method of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). It will automatically adjust to last day of month, if too large:

> This method adds the specified amount to the months field in three steps:
>
> 1. Add the input months to the month-of-year field
> 2. Check if the resulting date would be invalid
> 3. **Adjust the day-of-month to the last valid day if necessary**

*Example*

```java
// Using loop
private static List<LocalDate> getDates(LocalDate firstDate, int count) {
    List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        dates.add(firstDate.plusMonths(i));
    return dates;
}
```

```java
// Using Java 8 Stream
private static List<LocalDate> getDates(LocalDate firstDate, int count) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, count)
                    .mapToObj(i -> firstDate.plusMonths(i))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(getDates(LocalDate.of(2016, 3, 11), 6));
System.out.println(getDates(LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 31), 6));
```

*Output*

```
[2016-03-11, 2016-04-11, 2016-05-11, 2016-06-11, 2016-07-11, 2016-08-11, 2016-09-11]
[2016-01-31, 2016-02-29, 2016-03-31, 2016-04-30, 2016-05-31, 2016-06-30, 2016-07-31]
```

<sup>*Note:* Used 2016 to show that it's leap year aware.</sup>

Comment: i'm using jdk 7 and i think localdate is not available in jdk 7 so is there any alternating option.

Comment: @Moheb One way is to get the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).